# Simpliest way to remember DropDown selection?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, selection

I have;

```
<form method="post" action="search.php">
  <select name="country">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>   
    <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

And then in search.php `$country = $country` query MySQL table for column that's %like% country.

I wonder what is the simplest way to remember dropdown selection after someone makes pick up country?

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using the `selected` attribute on the `option` element. If you're populating the `select` element from an array or database query, you can do this:

```
<?php foreach($countries as $country): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $country ?>"<?php if($_POST['country'] == $country) { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>><?php echo $country ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Also, as a side note it's better to assign $country as follows:

```
$country = $_POST['country'];
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the feedback! 

Is there any explanation why is better to use POST then just $countr = $country ? 

Also Ive populated dropdown in HTML, 

Is there any way to leave it selected with php or should I better use Jquery / javascript.. ? Im searching for the simpliest solution..

Comment: The solution that I posted *is* written in PHP. You could use jQuery if you so wish, but using PHP is probably the easiest solution. You should avoid using `$country = $county` for portability reasons. `register_globals` has been deprecated, and so we will likely see it disappearing in PHP configurations not too long from now: http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you're doing on the server side, your rendered HTML should use the attribute `selected="selected"` on the `<option>` you want it to be initially selected.