# PHP Menu Select Option values

Tags: php, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a form and a drop down menu for users to select Industy Job Sectors as part of their search, e.g. Accountancy, Construction, Engineering etc.

I've searched this forum for solutions regarding how to remember menu select option values AFTER submit and I'm grateful to have implemented a modified version from the solution I found here:
[Simpliest way to remember DropDown selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782116/simpliest-way-to-remember-dropdown-selection)

```
//For example

if(is_post_request()) {
  $jobsector['jobsector_id'] = $_POST['jobsector_id'] ?? '';
} else {
$jobsector['jobsector_id'] = '';
}


<div class="form-group">
  <label for="jobsector">Job Sector:</label>
  <select class="custom-select" name="jobsector_id" id="jobsector_id">
    <option value="">Select Sector</option>
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT jobsectors.id, jobsectors.jobsector_name FROM jobsectors";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    $_SESSION['jobsector_id'] = $jobsector['jobsector_id'];
    $_POST['jobsector_id'] = $_SESSION['jobsector_id'];

    //loop
    foreach ($results as $jobsector): ?>
      <option value="<?php echo h($jobsector['jobsector_name']); ?>"
        <?php if ($jobsector['jobsector_name'] == $_POST['jobsector_id']){echo " selected";}?>>
        <?= $jobsector['jobsector_name']; ?>
      </option>
      <?php endforeach;
      unset ($_SESSION['jobsector_id']); ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

However, I've run in to a problem where the menu select option values that I have, BEFORE the form is submitted, now show a notice/error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: jobsector_id
```

Here's a screen grab:
[screenshot of undefined index notice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDm0A.gif)

I realise that this will be because the POST value for 'jobsector_id' has not yet been submitted with the form, so my question is how do I get the menu select options to show in the drop down without this error, BEFORE the form is submitted?

Comment: Is this code snippet from your application or is this an example bit of code? If it's an example, please can you provide snippets of code from your application.

Comment: It's because you're trying to access the value of a variable that is not set. Instead of `else` you try in your foreach `if($_POST['jobsector_id'] !== null)` , and then check what the variable is set to.

Comment: Hi FluxCoder. Thanks for your comment. The code snippet is from my development application for users to add jobs to a database. The full code 'requires in' many other files and SQL commands, so what would be the best way for me to provide more code snippets? :)

Comment: @user10341554. Thanks I tried that but the result always defaults to the last value in the select list.

Comment: So, the code snippet for the select menu works IF a user submits the form without first selecting a menu option because the $_POST value then has something to check against. What I'm stuck with is why the menu items are checking for the POST value before the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a session to store the value of 'jobsector_id' and then made $_POST['jobsector_id'] = $_SESSION['jobsector_id'] and finally unset the session. It all seems to work fine now. Thank you for your suggestions guys!